# Iphone restore stuck in recovery mode

Tags: restore, iphone, itunes

My Iphone 4 is stuck in recovery mode, I was wondering if I could restore phone in ubuntu. If possible please show how.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot restore your iPhone from Ubuntu. Restoring an iDevice requires iTunes, which is not available for Ubuntu.

Comment: What about a window simulator like wine

Comment: It does not work on wine. The only way at present is to run a virtual machine of an OS that can run itunes.

Comment: What virtual machine, would it be a simple installation to my computer